# Try/Catch within loop in C#

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally

There is a `try/catch/finally` block within the `for` or `foreach` loop.

What will happen  if there is a `break` statement within the `try` block?

Will `finally` block be executed?

Comment: Try it and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, finally blocks hit even if you have a jump statement such as `break`.

> Typically, the statements of a finally block run when control leaves a
>   try statement.The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal execution, of execution of a break, continue, goto, or return statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It will. You can try to run the following example

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                if (i == 3)
                    break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("finally");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will get hit. Here's a sample code you can try.

```
        var intList = new List<int>{5};

        foreach(var intItem in intList)
        {
            try
            {
              if(intItem == 5)
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Catch reached");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Finally reached");
            }
        }
```

Output : Finally Reached

Answer (score 1):

YES it will hit `finally`. [Try Me.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BUtGHN)
Below will confirm my answer:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (i == 10)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Catch");
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("finally");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
finally
1
finally
2
finally
3
finally
4
finally
5
finally
6
finally
7
finally
8
finally
9
finally
finally
```